# Modern kitchen drawer help

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, photorealism

I am trying to model a 'Modern kitchen' with [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyXRBu7gn2o) as a base guide. I have already modeled the exterior assets. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to model those indentations in the left side. Please help[image: [The original image]

The original image
[image: The CG render]
The CG render

Comment: Hello and welcome :). What *exactly* is your question? Please keep it one question per post. You can post as many separate questions as needed.

Comment: What "indentations" we are talking about? Maybe a nice little arrow or a circle in those screenshots would be nice? Or a render from a different angle that shows the detail instead of the whole scene? My Magic 8-Ball has no clue, either...

Comment: Sorry. If you look to the left on the cabinet section, you will see indentations where the drawers and cabinets are separated. That is what I am talking about.